# Finding the vertex of a cone

Tags: quadratic-forms

Let a 3D, circular cone of vertex $\vec{v}=[v_x,v_y,v_z]$ given by the equation: 
$$ (x-v_x)^2+(y-v_y)^2=(z-v_z)^2 $$
The equation of this cone can also be written as:
$$ 
(\vec{x}-\vec{v})^TA(\vec{x}-\vec{v})=0, \textrm{ with } A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Given a set of measurements $\begin{Bmatrix}{\vec{x_1},\dotsc,\vec{x_n}}\end{Bmatrix}$ of points that should belong to this cone, how to find analytically the vertex $\vec{v}$?

Comment: So let us make things more precise : you look for "a best fitted cone" : thus it is in the sense of **mean squares** ; thus you have to measure the distance between your points/vectors and the general cone in order to minimize the sum of the squares of these distances to the cone.

Comment: Indeed I'm looking for a best fitted cone, whose equation shall respect the one given in the wording of the problem. In other words, the matrix $A$ is fixed beforehand, and I need to calculate analytically the vertex $\vec{v}$ thanks to matrix $X=\begin{bmatrix}\vec{x_1}\cdots\vec{x_n}\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @charlie, the way, that you want to solve it, is not valid. Because the result is a matrix with zeros on the diagonal. But you cannot be sure that the same is true for the off-diagonal entries of the matrix.